# Method changes on fetch depending on where it is called from on Svelte

Tags: javascript, rest, cors, svelte

For context, I am using go-gonic for my Backend and Svelte for my Frontend.
The Backend I don't believe is the issue here, it works correctly with tests and an alternate cli Frontend in python, along with working in a rest client. I have narrowed down the issue to the Svelte component, and the async function inside of it.

Summary: When I try to call a fetch with method `POST` from the on:click handler in Svelte it switches the method to `OPTIONS`, but when I call the fetch with method `POST` in the main body of the component when it first loads, the method stays as `POST`. (The method changes only when called from on:click)

I am writing a component that calls an endpoint from the Backend

1. as soon as it is loaded (GET)
2. when a button is click (POST)

For the first (GET), I call my API inside an OnMount like so (this works)

```js
  onMount(async () => {
    await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:1357/api/v1/col/`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("Admin:stackoverflow<3"),
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((data) => {
        cols = JSON.parse(data["message"]);
      });
  });
```

But for the second one (POST), I want to call a fetch when a button is clicked.
Here is how I am doing that. This was the recommended way to call a function on click in svelte (the arrow syntax is there because I want to include parameters, but those are excluded for simplicity.)

```html
<input
  class="flat submit"
  type="submit"
  value="+"
  on:click={async () => newStep()}
/>
```

Here is the definition of newStep.

```js
  async function newStep() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", "NAME");
    formData.append("desc", "DESC");
    formData.append("collection", selected);

    await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:1357/api/v1/step/`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("Admin:stackoverflow<3"),
      },
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

When the submit button is clicked, is attempts to make a fetch that is registered in the Backend, except the method is `OPTIONS` and not `POST`.

Here might be a hint. This code works as expect (POST is made) when the body of function is run at the start of the code like so. To clarify, the body of the function runs as expected when it is not in a function, but when run as the component is loaded. The code only breaks (Makes request of method `OPTIONS`) when it is run inside a async function. I also tested with a non async function. The problem for some reason happens whenever I wrap this code in a function and then try to call it on click. When the fetch changes method to `OPTIONS`, it will put this in the console. `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

```js
<script>
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", "NAME");
    formData.append("desc", "DESC");
    formData.append("collection", selected);

    await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:1357/api/v1/step/`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("Admin:stackoverflow<3"),
      },
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
</script>
```

I think I am following all of the recommended ways to do this, but I may have missed something, if there is a good library, similar to react-query to help alleviate issues like this involving async and fetch, that would help as well. My main goal is to call a fetch with method `POST` when a button is clicked and if there are betters ways to do this, that would help.

p.s. I use a better method for auth than in these examples.

Thanks in advance.

(edit): Add info from console.

Comment: The OPTIONS call is CORS preflight. The browser will use OPTIONS before POST to determine if the server can handle the request. If your server responds correctly to OPTIONS, the POST request will be issued,

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I need to make a route specifically for OPTIONS and return certain headers right?

Comment: Usually, this can be done by using a CORS middleware at the server level, or at the reverse proxy/ingress level. But that's the idea: you have to return the correct CORS headers to the client.

Comment: Is there a good way to check which headers are needed?